# Android - Scale view horizontally when dragging from the left or the right side

Tags: android, view, resize, scale

[image]

I want to scale view when dragging the arrows views, it works with me when

> setPivotX = 0

and drag the right arrow
but when do the same with the left arrow the red view doesn't scale for the left side however I tried to change the pivotX to the width of the view.